# Ruby/Rails - Adding a Poll to Site

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a current Rails 3 app and I'd like to run a poll on my site to get user opinions...

Just wondering if anyone has used a polling gem/plugin or possible a widget solution to handle this problem..

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look at [Surveyor](http://vimeo.com/7051279) ([GitHub](https://github.com/NUBIC/Surveyor)).